# Integrating Raspberry Camera with ROS2

Tags: camera, ubuntu-20.04, raspberry-pi4, robotics, ros2

I am trying to integrate raspberrypi camera into my robotic project. I have tried modules 2 and 3.  same result. I'm using ROS-FOXY( ubuntu 20.04) and ROS HUMBLE(ubuntu 22).
I installed  the driver using

```
sudo apt install libraspberrypi-bin v4l-utils ros-foxy-v4l2-camera ros-foxy-image-transport-plugins
```

vcgencmd get_camera shows ***" 0 detected 0 supported "*** both in ros-foxy and ros-humble.

The cameras were detected when with raspberrypi OS, but not with Ubuntu.
***using v4l2-ctl --list-devices*** shows

```
Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.
```

Anybody with a clue as to what is missing?